# Combining effects of dummy variables in a regression model

Tags: python, sas, regression, random-forest, dummy-variable

I am building a regression model with about 300 features using Python Sklearn. One of the features has over 100 categories and I end up having ~100 dummy columns for this feature.Now each of the dummy column has its own coefficient, or a feature ranking score (if using Random Forest or xgb) - which is something I dont like.  However, when I create the same model in SAS JMP, it gives me one single feature score for the feature with 100 categories -it apparently handles categories automatically. Can someone tell me how SAS JMP combines the coefficients/feature importances of 100 dummy variables into one metric. And how can i can achieve the same in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how SAS JMP does it, but I think it works by not using dummy variables. Tree Based models actually natively support categorial data, it's just not implemented by sklearn ([yet](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/4899)). Furthermore, at least in some cases introducing dummy variables reduces the accuracy of the model as shown by [this blog post](https://roamanalytics.com/2016/10/28/are-categorical-variables-getting-lost-in-your-random-forests/).

You can look into using another package such as the one used by the blog post (H2O).

Answer (score 0):

You may google SAS STAT manual /User guide. Check out any major regression procedures there that support Class statement. Underneath the Class it details Reference... option. They all detail how a design matrix is fashioned out. The way you fed your 100 dummies must have been obvious enough to trigger JMP to roll back to a temp class variable that re-engineer back to one single variable. If you want to know how exactly JMP is triggered to do roll back, go to JMP website and open a technical support track. But mechanically I am confident this is what happens.